# Viewing custom attributes of a file within Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Within Nautilus I can right-click a file and view the file properties. I want to set custom file properties myself. Linux attr would do. So first I installed the attr :

```
 sudo apt-get install attr
```

Then I created a test-1.txt file. And assigned attributes with :

```
setfattr -n user.testing -v "this is a test" test-1.txt
```

To read the attributes I use :

```
getfattr -n user.testing test-1.txt
```

So I can write and read my custom file attributes (properties). The origin source of this example is on :    http://archive09.linux.com/feature/114027  But these properties are not visible in Nautilus. How can I make my custom properties visible in Nautilus?
I copied the test-1.txt file to a Windows 8 system and checked the properties. Also on the Windows 8 system these properties are not visible. So it might be attr itself, which does not set the properties which are 'readable' by file managers. I know sometimes properties get lost when copied, so the problem might also be coming from here.